# Show Text, Button and Pause

Tags: c#, .net

I would like to show the user some text and pause the code. After he read the text, he should use a button to go on.
That's what I got:

```
        bool weiter = false;
        private void xy()
        {
            //some code before
            label1.Text = "Some text here";
            button2.Visible = true;
            while (!weiter)
            {
            }
            button2.Visible = false;
            weiter = false;
            //some code afterwards
        }
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            weiter = true;
        }
```

Problem: The Form is freezed and the button won't pop up...
Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MessageBox.Show(string)` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/519bytz3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx does just this. It shows a message box and blocks until the user clicks on "Ok".

Answer (score 0):

If you put an infinite loop on your main thread, no other code will ever be able to execute (including the UI code that listens for button clicks).  Can't you simply just restructure the code to look more like this:

```
private void xy()
{
    //some code before
    label1.Text = "Some text here";
    button2.Visible = true;
}
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button2.Visible = false;
    //rest of your code
}
```

Comment: I would like to use this button to go on at different lines in the code... Do I have to create a button for each situation?

Comment: Almost certainly not, but hard to give further advice without more information.  The message box construct can likely achieve this for you, if you don't like that, it's probably not to difficult to re-create without having to have a pop-up come up constantly.

Answer (score 0):

If you write between braces of `while` loop `Applicaion.DoEvents();` form is does not freeze.